# Using float numbers in knife's angle constraint

Tags: knife-tool

how do I use float numbers (0.5, 22.5, etc) in the angle constraint when using the knife tool? Whenever I try typing 22 and then the .5, it just resets and goes to 5 instead.

[image]

[image]

I'm using Blender 3.2.0

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a limit rotation constraint?  I'm having trouble reproducing your issue with that constraint, and am unaware of any "angle constraint".

Comment: @Nathan Well, when using the knife tool you're able to use an 'angle constraint' so you can cut things more straight, however when I try to type '22.5', it just goes to 5 because it 'resets' when I type the '.'

So right now I can only use like 1, 2, 3, whatever, but not 2.5, 4.5, 22.5, etc

(As shown in the pictures above)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense-- there are some other places where people might talk about an "angle constraint" and that affects how they interpret the question.  If you don't mind, I'll edit your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the knife tool to be constrained to any particular axis, you can choose the knife tool from the toolbar, then specify angle snapping and any arbitrary angle you'd like in properties/tool:

[image]

Here, I've specified a 22.5 degree angle constrain to screen, and I've demonstrated the cut I've made with that.

Comment: Hey, apologies for the late reply. How were you able to type '22.5'? Whenever I try typing that, it goes to '22' but when I type the dot '.' and then the 5, it'll just say 5.

Comment: @BrightParts I used my numpad, but regular numbers and period work for me as well.  Perhaps you have a conflicting keybinding?  Personally, I use old-school interface, pre-2.8 keybinds, right click select, etc.